# Getting the same response to requests GET when there should be another one?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am very new to using `API`'s, I am trying to figure out how to get the response to a `POST`.

Using Ubuntu. I have set-up a server for POSTBACK on ngrok. I am using an `API` to place order. Which showes me a response code of 200 on the ngrok terminal. Which shows data.
Screenshot:
[image]

I am trying to get this data but I when I:

```
requests.get('http://f3afa497.ngrok.io:80/').text
```

The POSTBACK Url in the app is: `https:` can this be an issue?

I always get the same text:

> '{"placed_by":"TY5094","order_id":"190106000009064","exchange_order_id":"","parent_order_id":"","status":"REJECTED","status_message":"RMS:Blocked for  EQUITY  nse_cm  NRML Remarks: Equity orders are not allowed in NRML product type  block type: ALL","order_timestamp":"2019-01-06 18:37:21","exchange_update_timestamp":"","exchange_timestamp":"","variety":"regular","exchange":"NSE","tradingsymbol":"INFY","instrument_token":408065,"order_type":"MARKET","transaction_type":"BUY","validity":"DAY","product":"NRML","quantity":1,"disclosed_quantity":0,"price":0,"trigger_price":0,"average_price":0,"filled_quantity":0,"pending_quantity":0,"cancelled_quantity":0,"market_protection":0,"tag":""\n}'

Which is from a post request way before the latest. See the order_id

I am wondering what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: Your screenshot shows a `post` request... your code is making a `get` request... are you comparing the right things here?

Comment: @JonClements I am very new to interacting with a POSTBACK url. I thought get was the way to receive data of the `post`.

Comment: Nope - get/post will both potentially return something - it's just a different verb to the server to know how to handle it/accept data... Have a look at `requests.post` and make that do the same as the post request you see in ngrok